# ASP.Net MVC - dropdown list for associated objects

Tags: asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

I have two models in my application: `Product` and `ProductType`. `Product` has a reference to `ProductType` (in the DB it's named `ProductTypeId`), while `ProductType` has two columns (`Id` and `Name`).

I can get the dropdown to be properly populated and displayed on the forum using the following code:

#### Controller:

```
var typeList = new SelectList(_entities.ProductType.ToList(), "Id", "Name");
ViewData["Types"] = typeList;
```

#### View:

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("ProductType", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>) ViewData["Types"]) %>
```

However my problem becomes that it's not updating the model back in the Controller.  If I leave the code as is, then the ModelState is invalid because of the `ProductType` string in the view, However, if I change it to anything else, it seems I can no longer refer to it within the controller.

Comment: Are you binding this info to a model in your controller

ex: ViewData.Model=typeList

and in use it in your view also

Comment: I'm not because the object that I'm looking to update is actually the Product, not the ProductType

Answer (score 3):

I just tried the very same thing and it worked for me just fine

controller:

```
 public ActionResult Create()
    {
    configuratorDataContext dc = new configuratorDataContext();
    SelectList typelist = new SelectList(dc.Product_types.ToList(), "id", "Name");
    ViewData["Product_Types"] = typelist;
    ViewData.Model = new Product(); 
    return View();
    } 

    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Create(Product createProduct)
    {
    // createProduct here contains correct type_id wich 
    }
```

view:

```
  <%= Html.DropDownList("type_id", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>) ViewData["Product_Types"])%>
```